# ELK – Logstash Email Alerting Config Issues

Tags: ruby, json, logstash, logstash-grok, elastic-stack

I've been playing around with logstash and wanting to know how to exactly configure email alerting correctly.

I'm looking to pick up the string "BVDCS_LAP" and send a mail onto that address given.

The config I have is:

```html
input {
  udp {
    port => 5000
    type => syslog
  }
}
filter {
  if [type] == "syslog" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
    }
    syslog_pri { }
    date {
      match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    }
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch { host => localhost }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
  email {
    from => "mymail@domain"
    match =>  {
               "BVDCS_LAP", "message,BVDCS_LAP",
               "BVDCS_LAP", "message,BVDCS_LAP"
              }
    subject => "%{matchName}"
    to => "mymail@domain"
    via => "smtp"
    body => "Here is the event line that occured: %{message}"
    htmlbody => "<h2>%{matchName}</h2><br/><br/><h3>Full Event</h3><br/><br/><div align='center'>%{@message}</div>"
  }
}
```

E-mails are not being sent and in my logstash.conf I'm seeing the below on line 27:

{:timestamp=>"2015-07-07T12:55:50.597000+0100", :message=>"Error: Expected one of #, input, filter, output at line 27, column 8 (byte 649) after "}

I’m curious as well to know if my original grok coding is correct and also if we could work out how to set a tag for a syslog message and use that as the email output?

Thanks

Comment: What is the `match` parameter for the email output supposed to mean? According to the documentation it's not even a valid parameter. If you want a conditional email output you should use a conditional block.

Answer (score 0):

Logstash is not really built for alerts. I've seen a couple of people try to use it but it was very limited (single strings) and worked only in very small scale.

You can try a solution like Logz.io (disclaimer: I work there) which offers alerts on top of logstash/Elasticsearch. You ship logs from your logstash to Logz.io, then configure the string you're looking and it sends you email alerts when that string matches.

Comment: Thanks but that looks payware and does it require replacement of kIbana as the UI?

Comment: No need for any replacement, it offers Kibana 4 frontend. It is a paid service but there is a pretty large free tier (up to 30GB per months) for free.  Another alternative is to  build an alert system on top of the open source ELK and install it in-house. Not trivial to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this last year using the email plugin with conditional script blocks as Magnus advised.

Happy to add some samples if anyone needs them.